# How to separate a string of numbers entered in a loop?

Tags: java

I need help pulling the numbers out and separating them by commas, for example, if I enter 1  2  3  4  5, it should print out

```
Entered Numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
The Sum: 15
```

instead I get this

```
Entered Numbers: 12345
The Sum: 15
```

Code:

```
/*A program that prompts the user to enter a positive integer number. The program should accept integers until the user enters the 
value -1 (negative one). After the user enters -1, the program should display the entered numbers followed by their sum*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      //create a way to receive user input
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Variables
      int sum = 0;
      String value;

      //Input
      System.out.println("Enter a positive integer (Enter -1 to quit): ");
      value = input.nextLine();

      String x = "";

      //Loop Statements
      while (Integer.parseInt(value) != -1)
         {
            sum = Integer.parseInt(value) + sum;
            x = x + value;
            value = input.nextLine();
         }
      //Output
      System.out.println("Entered Numbers: " + x);
      System.out.println("The sum: " + sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: Where are you inserting the commas?

Comment: After the user enters a -1 to exit the loop, it should print out all the numbers they entered while in the loop and then the sum. When it prints out the numbers, I want it to print out each individual number with commas and spaces after each one, but instead I get all the numbers pushed together.

Comment: My point is, that's because you haven't written any code to insert commas.

Comment: It is because everything I tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace() to do what yo want it to. Use it in this format

```
value = value.replace(" ", ","); //First param is the char you want to replace; The second is the one you want to replace the first param with
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Split string method to get each number then use trim to get stint with spaces. Then paste that string into an int and the ad it to the sum. Only the loop part has changed. everything else remains the same.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  //create a way to receive user input
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Variables
  int sum = 0;
  String value;

  //Input
  System.out.println("Enter a positive integer (Enter -1 to quit): ");
  value = input.nextLine();

  for(String eachNum:value.split(",")) {
     sum=Interger.parseInt(eachNum.trim());
  }

  //Output
  System.out.println("Entered Numbers: " + value);
  System.out.println("The sum: " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String x = "";

//Loop Statements
while (Integer.parseInt(value) != -1
     {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(value) + sum;
        x = x + value;
        value = input.nextLine();
     }
```

with

```
 String x = value;

  //Loop Statements
  while (Integer.parseInt(value) != -1)
     {
        sum = Integer.parseInt(value) + sum;
        x = x + ", " + value;
        value = input.nextLine();
     }
```